# SQL Server, running total, reset for each month and sum again

Tags: sql-server, conditional-statements, cumulative-sum

I have a calendar table where working days are marked.
Now I need a running total called "current_working_day" which sums up the working days until the end of a month and restarts again.

This is my query:

```
select
WDAYS.Date,
WDAYS.DayName,
WDAYS.WorkingDay,
sum(WDAYS.WorkingDay) OVER(order by (Date), MONTH(Date), YEAR(Date))  as 'current_working_day',
sum(WDAYS.WorkingDay) OVER(PARTITION by YEAR(WDAYS.Date), MONTH(WDAYS.Date) ) total_working_days_per_month
from WDAYS
where YEAR(WDAYS.Date) = 2022
```

This is my current output

| Date | DayName | WorkingDay | current_working_day | total_working_days_per_month |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-27 | Thursday | 1 | 19 | 21 |
| 2022-01-28 | Friday | 1 | 20 | 21 |
| 2022-01-29 | Saturday | 0 | 20 | 21 |
| 2022-01-30 | Sunday | 0 | 20 | 21 |
| 2022-01-31 | Monday | 1 | 21 | 21 |
| 2022-02-01 | Tuesday | 1 | 22 | 20 |
| 2022-02-02 | Wednesday | 1 | 23 | 20 |
| 2022-02-03 | Thursday | 1 | 24 | 20 |

But the column "current_workind_day" should be like this

| Date | DayName | WorkingDay | current_working_day | total_working_days_per_month |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-27 | Thursday | 1 | 19 | 21 |
| 2022-01-28 | Friday | 1 | 20 | 21 |
| 2022-01-29 | Saturday | 0 | 20 | 21 |
| 2022-01-30 | Sunday | 0 | 20 | 21 |
| 2022-01-31 | Monday | 1 | 21 | 21 |
| 2022-02-01 | Tuesday | 1 | 1 | 20 |
| 2022-02-02 | Wednesday | 1 | 2 | 20 |
| 2022-02-03 | Thursday | 1 | 3 | 20 |

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: You will get better performance if you use a sarge-able `WHERE` clause (no functions on columns) such as `WHERE WDAYS.Date >= '20220101' AND WDAYS.Date < '20230101'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use `PARTITION by` with `EOMONTH` function which might get the same result but better performance, then you might only need to order by `Date` instead of using the function with the date.

```
select
  WDAYS.Date,
  WDAYS.DayName,
  WDAYS.WorkingDay,
  sum(WDAYS.WorkingDay) OVER(PARTITION by EOMONTH(WDAYS.Date) order by Date)  as 'current_working_day',
  sum(WDAYS.WorkingDay) OVER(PARTITION by EOMONTH(WDAYS.Date) ) total_working_days_per_month
from WDAYS
where YEAR(WDAYS.Date) = 2022
```

Comment: I don't think you need `YEAR(WDAYS.Date)` in either `OVER()` clause?

Comment: @AaronBertrand Yes it might be removed due to the where clause

Comment: Regardless of the where clause, partitioning by year first doesn't segment the data any further than EOMONTH does on its own. It's still going to partition Feb 2022 separately from Feb 2021, whether you use YEAR() or not. Anyway, yes, this was the problem in the original query: one window function used partitioning, and the other did not.

Comment: Thanks, never used EOMONTH before. :-)